# Swift compilation discrepancy in version 2.1.1 and xcode 7.2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

We have latest Xcode(7.2) having Swift(2.1.1) installed in few mac systems. Here developer didn't find any errors in his code which was checked in, but the same code used at other end were observing errors(most of them related unwrapping variables).

verified all settings and version details not able to find any difference. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the machine "at the other end" is not running Xcode 7.2. There is a tool for converting Swift 1.x to 2.x, but not the other direction. But without code sample illustrating the problem, we can't help you much. In addition to shifting unwrapping conventions, there is new syntax later versions of Swift (e.g. `guard`, error throwing, etc.).

But, if you're going to share a Swift project amongst multiple developers, you probably just want to make sure everyone is using the same version of Xcode. And with Swift progressing as quickly as it is, you might want to encourage everyone to use the latest production version of Xcode.

Comment: yes, its confirmed that other end is also using Xcode 7.2 and Swift 2.2.1.  Let me try with Guard in coding and see if it help. Also will share the code snippet soon for more analysis